# Getting BOOL value on NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios

Inside my viewDidLoad I have the following. But I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

```
[led.highlighted: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"led"]];
```

and I also tried

```
[led.highlighted setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"led"]];
```

but that one errors with "Bad Receiver type 'BOOL'"

My method that sets the value from an IBAction seems to be OK.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:led.isHighlighted forKey:@"led"];
```

So how exactly do I return the value of led.highlighted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`led.highlighted` accesses the property; depending on it being on the right- or left-hand side of a statement, it uses the getter or the setter, respectively.

```
led.highlighted = YES;
// Equivalent to: [led setHighlighted:YES];
BOOL thatLEDIsLitUp = led.highlighted;
// Equivalent to: BOOL thatLEDIsLitUp = [led highlighted];
```

This assumes that you haven't changed the getter and setter names to `isHighlighted` and `setIsHighlighted:`

Given that, to set the property you can do either:

```
led.highlighted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"led"];
```

or

```
[led setHighlighted:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"led"]];
```

Your first attempt, `[led.highlighted:...]` is just incorrect syntax. The second, `[led.highlighted setValue:...]` uses the accessor to get `highlighted`, which is a `BOOL`, and then tries to send a message to it. `BOOL`s aren't objects, so you can't send messages to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
led.highlighted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"led"];
```

as long as your `highlighted` property is
`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL highlighted;`